# Having issues handling multiple JSON files

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I currently have a file that has multiple jsons that are not in a list or separated by commas (kind of like

`{id: 1, attributes{height:1, length:2}}{id: 2, attributes{height:4, length:1}}`).

I am trying to upload them to dynamoDB using .put_item(Item=json.loads(...)) from boto3, so I need to get it in the right format. I am currently using `jsonFileReader = jsonFileReader.decode().replace('}{', '},{')` to get the jsons in the right format, however, this makes them into a string (confirmed by using the type function), so I can not do a for loop on it and pass it to the .put_item function this way. How can I turn it into a list from a string so I can pass it in the for loop?

Comment: Putting multiple JSONs in a file is a bad idea. There's no reliable way to delimit them.

Comment: Fix the way you create the file.

Comment: BTW, even if you would split this into individual "json" strings, e.g. `{id: 1, attributes{height:1, length:2}}`, that would also not be valid json. You should produce valid json files and then use that.

Comment: I can, but ideally I would like not to. The file is created this way by kinesis firehose, and to use the jsons individually, I would have to cut out firehose which would not be ideal.

Answer (score 1):

Could something like this work for you?:

```
import json

# get file data
raw_data = open("multi_json.json", "rt").read()

# make it look like an array of objects
array_string = "[" + raw_data.replace("}{","},{") + "]"

# convert to object list with json
object_list = json.loads(array_string)

# then do whatever you want with your list of objects.
```

Comment: I believe json.loads only works with a single json object, not a list

Comment: json.dumps had no problem with a list. I ran a quick test.  Seemed to work fine.  I'll try with the OP code.

Comment: I was just typing it out wrong. Your method worked perfectly. Thank you!